# Does apt-cacher change packages access time?

Tags: 12.04, apt, proxy, find, apt-cacher

I tried to remove the long time unused packages from `apt-cacher` archive using `find`:

```
$ find /var/cache/apt-cacher -atime +5 -type f -name ".*deb*" | wc -l 8471
$ find /var/cache/apt-cacher -atime +9 -type f -name ".*deb*" | wc -l 2269
$ find /var/cache/apt-cacher -atime +10 -type f -name ".*deb*" | wc -l 0
```

Can I depend on the "Access Time" for apt-cacher archive usage?

That is, does "Access Time" change only when package get received by the user?

We are using apt-cacher for more than 6 months.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I list the unused applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247841/how-can-i-list-the-unused-applications)

Comment: The question deals with another problem. So I wouldn't consider them duplicates.

Comment: snow: I mostly want to know how apt-cacher act with its list of packages.It might be better to present this at apt-cacher developer mail-list.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the `atime` on your files is properly kept? Many filesystems use mounted nowadays with `noatime` or `relatime` options to reduce the amount to writes to the disk.

Those options influence how and how often the `atime` stat field is written.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apt- catcher is an apt-proxy. It has the ability to catch the packages you download locally each time an update is made in your system.

Comment: so,you don't answer my question.