# How can I list the unused applications?

Tags: software-recommendation

Hey is there any possibility to list out all the applications with a condition of unused for 10-20 days limit. If so how can I do that .

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The closest I can think of is to run `popularity-contest > out.txt` which will take a while to generate a file, `out.txt`, listing programs, from most recently used to least recently used. I get the impression that ...

- The first column is the most recent time (epoch format) the program was used
  and the next column is the time it was first used (or installed?).
- The only programs listed are, I think, programs that are registered
  (as a result of being installed via `apt-get` or the Software Center).
  Those that aren't, don't figure in the list. For example, I installed
  Seamonkey by uncompressing a tar.gz. That doesn't show.

The output of `popularity-contest` looks like this:

```
POPULARITY-CONTEST-0 TIME:1359204011 ID:ae1dc87f150c489082f0ddb28af40350 ARCH:i386 POPCONVER:1.53ubuntu1
1359204011 1349657211 openbox /usr/bin/openbox
1359204011 1349657211 xscreensaver /usr/bin/xscreensaver
1359204011 1354294761 perl-base /usr/bin/perl
1359204011 1349833421 update-notifier /usr/bin/update-notifier
1359204011 1349657224 xfconf /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
1359204011 1349657224 lxpanel /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lxpanel/plugins/monitors.so
1359204011 1349657225 policykit-1-gnome /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
1359204011 1358559008 lxterminal /usr/bin/lxterminal
1359204011 1349664550 ttf-ubuntu-font-family /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-RI.ttf
1359204011 1349664535 pcmanfm /usr/bin/pcmanfm
1359204011 1349657224 lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lxpanel/plugins/indicator.so
1359204011 1349657235 ttf-dejavu-core /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
1359204011 1349657210 lxsession /usr/bin/lxsession
1359204011 1349833422 update-notifier-common /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/update-notifier.mo
1359204011 1349664531 network-manager-gnome /usr/bin/nm-applet
1359204011 1349657205 zlib1g /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
1359204011 1352212906 xfce4-power-manager /usr/bin/xfce4-power-manager
1359204008 1349657221 libxfconf-0-2 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxfconf-0.so.2.0.0
1359204008 1358215752 libnss3 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libfreebl3.so
1359204008 1349657221 libvorbis0a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.5
1359204008 1349657221 libvorbisenc2 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.8
1359204008 1349657217 libxcursor1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
1359204008 1349657217 libx11-6 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
1359204008 1349657221 libtasn1-3 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.16
1359204008 1349657221 libwind0-heimdal /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
```

The first two columns can be converted by pasting the entire output into a spreadsheet. I used LibreOffice Calc for the purpose and inserted blank columns after each column of "epoch time". I then filled down with [a formula to convert "epoch time" to human-readable time](http://www.epochconverter.com/) (and using Format, Cells, Time to get a suitable format).

For the first row of data, assuming the first "epoch time" cell is in A2, put `=(A2/86400)+25569` in B2 and fill down. Do the same for the second "epoch time", using `=(C2/86400)+25569` in cell D2.

The content, just a few lines, then looks like this:

```
POPULARITY-CONTEST-0        TIME:1359204011     ID:ae1dc87f150c489082f0ddb28af40350 ARCH:i386
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657211  08/10/2012 00:46:51 openbox /usr/bin/openbox
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657211  08/10/2012 00:46:51 xscreensaver    /usr/bin/xscreensaver
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1354294761  30/11/2012 16:59:21 perl-base   /usr/bin/perl
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349833421  10/10/2012 01:43:41 update-notifier /usr/bin/update-notifier
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657224  08/10/2012 00:47:04 xfconf  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657224  08/10/2012 00:47:04 lxpanel /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lxpanel/plugins/monitors.so
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657225  08/10/2012 00:47:05 policykit-1-gnome   /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1358559008  19/01/2013 01:30:08 lxterminal  /usr/bin/lxterminal
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349664550  08/10/2012 02:49:10 ttf-ubuntu-font-family  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-RI.ttf
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349664535  08/10/2012 02:48:55 pcmanfm /usr/bin/pcmanfm
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657224  08/10/2012 00:47:04 lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lxpanel/plugins/indicator.so
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657235  08/10/2012 00:47:15 ttf-dejavu-core /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657210  08/10/2012 00:46:50 lxsession   /usr/bin/lxsession
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349833422  10/10/2012 01:43:42 update-notifier-common  /usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/update-notifier.mo
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349664531  08/10/2012 02:48:51 network-manager-gnome   /usr/bin/nm-applet
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1349657205  08/10/2012 00:46:45 zlib1g  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
1359204011  26/01/2013 12:40:11 1352212906  06/11/2012 14:41:46 xfce4-power-manager /usr/bin/xfce4-power-manager
1359204008  26/01/2013 12:40:08 1349657221  08/10/2012 00:47:01 libxfconf-0-2   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxfconf-0.so.2.0.0
1359204008  26/01/2013 12:40:08 1358215752  15/01/2013 02:09:12 libnss3 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nss/libfreebl3.so
1359204008  26/01/2013 12:40:08 1349657221  08/10/2012 00:47:01 libvorbis0a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.5
1359204008  26/01/2013 12:40:08 1349657221  08/10/2012 00:47:01 libvorbisenc2   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.8
1359204008  26/01/2013 12:40:08 1349657217  08/10/2012 00:46:57 libxcursor1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
1359204008  26/01/2013 12:40:08 1349657217  08/10/2012 00:46:57 libx11-6    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
1359204008  26/01/2013 12:40:08 1349657221  08/10/2012 00:47:01 libtasn1-3  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.16
1359204008  26/01/2013 12:40:08 1349657221  08/10/2012 00:47:01 libwind0-heimdal    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
```

You can read more at popcon.ubuntu.com but a quote from there is here:

> Q) What information is reported by popularity-contest ?
>
> A) popularity-contest reports the system architecture you use, the
>   version of    popularity-contest you use and the list of packages
>   installed on your    system. For each package, popularity-contest
>   looks at the most recently used    (based on atime) files, and reports
>   the filename, its last access time    (atime) and last change time
>   (ctime). However, some files are not    considered, because they have
>   unreliable atime.

You can also run `man popularity-contest` for more information.

Comment: Hi Vasa1. Thanks for your great answer.I agree with your answer but I need to deal with apps which installed from source also.

Comment: Both are great answers.

Comment: so, if popularity contest tells me 0 0, is it safe to assume that the package was never used, and that I can remove it as long as my usage pattern won't change?

Answer (score 16):

You can use the access time to determine when an application was last used.

For example, try:

```
ls -ltu /usr/bin | pager
```

This will list all files under `/usr/bin` sorted by access time (last accessed first).

If you want to create a script that automatically finds programs with certain characteristics, you can use `stat` in this way:

```
stat -c%X /bin/cat
```

This will output the access time for `/bin/cat` as the number of seconds since Epoch

**Note:** obviously, this won't work if you are using the `noatime` mount option.

Comment: Both are great answers.

Answer (score 1):

My disk became full, so I used the following line to find all applications that were not used in the last 100 days, and whose binary file is larger than 1 MB:

```
find /usr/bin -size +1000k -atime +100 -exec ls -ltu {} \;
```